# Can't resolve creating a class which will initialise a line segment from a list of points

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, line, segment

I’m in a lot of trouble. I have a python assignment due in like 6 hours and I just can’t get my head around it. I have to create a class which will initialise a method for creating a line segment based on the index of a long list of points. So it’ll consist of `def __init__`, `def getstartsegment`, `def getendsegment`. Then I have to create a tester which will actually plot the points we have in a list already on a graph using matplotlib and pyplot. I am just screwed, suddenly I just can’t see the logic anymore.
I know eventually I'll have to create a plot vector method, just so confused.

```
class LineSegment:

    def __init__(self, start, end):
                self.start = start
                self.end = end
    def __str__(self):
                return "["+self.start.__str__()+"],["+self.end.__str__()+"]"
    def getstartseg(self, _allPoints):
        indices = []
        idx = -1
        while True:
           try:
              idx = _allPoints.index(self, idx+1)
              indices.append(idx)
           except ValueError:
               break
        return indices
        
    def getendseg(self, _allPoints):
        indices = []
        idx = 0
        while True:
            try:
                idx = _allPoints.index(self, idx+1)
                indices.append(idx)
            except ValueError:
                break
        return indices
```

This is what I have so far but doesn't really answer anything. Just trying any function with no structure

Comment: Some things need to be more clearly defined.  What is the purpose of the LineSegment class?  What is a start segment and end segment?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment of some sort?

Comment: Sorry, it is part of a larger practical, it's not assessed it's just for learning purposes. But I hate when the lecturer asks questions in class and I don't fully understand what's going on. So the objective of the line segment is to connect two points together from a specific index. The points follow an order and as such the line segments will.

Comment: It's important to note that the points are not simply x,y values but rather I've created a Point2D class which means each x and y value constitutes one point.

Comment: So, what are `start` and `end` if you don't use them only in `__init__`? I'd think they'd be the indices for `allPoints` (no need for an underscore), but apparently not. What is `allPoints`; I had guessed a list of n-dimensional points, but doesn't look like it. And why does a line segment need a start segment and an end segment; a segment has a start point and endpoint, not -segments.

Comment: allPoints is a list created with an array that contains all the point objects. And yeah, I made a mistake. The two functions for get start and get end are point based not new segments. They need to be seperate from _init_ because they need to be defined as the start and the end and a list will need to be passed with start and end points in each.